# Antiderivatives in C

Tags: c, integral, numerical-integration

I'm trying to create a c program that implements the radon transform algorithm. I know that for an image f(x,y) a collection of g(phi,s), at all phi is the randon transform of the image, where g(phi,s) is defined as:

[image]

Now, I don't have a lot of experience with C and I always used an external library with Java and C# to perform complex math operations. I'm having a hard time finding one for c, I'm also having trouble creating a function to do it, I've been looking into numerical integration but that is for definite integrals. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The rules for indefinite integrals are the same as for definite ones.  You just end up with an expression rather than a number.  :)

Comment: People at http://math.stackexchange.com might offer a better insight into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: there may be specialized implementations of Radon transform known to the image processing community. I don't know about those, I just approach the problem as an integration problem. I see eg. http://takinginitiative.net/2008/04/02/radon-transform-c-implementation-update/ that there may be some specific method for computing Radon transforms of images.*

What you are really doing here is a 1D integral along a line. See the 4th formula in the Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform .

If you are doing this over an image, the method you use for computing the integral will be quite dependent on the interpolation you choose. If you go for bilinear interpolation, then a plain (adaptive) trapezoidal rule will likely give you good results.

For C libraries to assist you, you can have a look at the [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/).

Answer (score 1):

and in general don't rely on your handwritten code for this kind of problems which are very complex in some case and have to be tested and stressed. If you program in C Gnu Scientific Library can help you in integral computation.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate `g(phi,s)` you could at least try the most basic summation.

First, sum up `f(x,y) * delta(x*sin(phi) - y*cos(phi) - s) * dx` for a given `y` and all `x` of the image using some small step `dx`. That's a loop in `x`. Then repeat the above for all `y` of the image using some small step `dy`. That's another loop, in `y`. Oh, and don't forget to multiply by `dy`. So you have two nested loops for `y` and `x` and inside you sum up `f(x,y) * delta(x*sin(phi) - y*cos(phi) - s) * dx * dy`, e.g. something like this:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>

double g(double phi, double s, double xmin, double xmax, double dx, double ymin, double ymax, double dy)
{
  double x, y, sum;

  assert(xmin <= xmax && dx > 0);
  assert(ymin <= ymax && dy > 0);

  sum = 0;

  for (y = ymin; y <= ymax; y += dy)
    for (x = xmin; x <= xmax; x += dx)
      sum += f(x,y) * delta(x*sin(phi) - y*cos(phi) - s) * dx * dy;

  return sum;
}
```

You only need to define `f()` to return the image data and `delta()` and choose appropriate `dx` and `dy` (not too big, not too small). That should give you some initial results.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: how about choosing sufficiently small dx and dy? And btw, what kind of delta are we talking about? Dirac delta function or something else?

Comment: The integral is really 1D, because of the Dirac function.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: but f(), image, is 2-d. OTOH, if you follow "non-zero" values of delta() for given inputs, then, then ues, it's 1d.

Comment: The Radon transform is the integral of f over a line. The formulation with the dirac function is not really useful for computations.